# Big white square while loading video kivy

Tags: python, video, kivy, kivy-language

I am making a video app that plays a video fullscreen, but when the video loads I see a pretty big white square in the bottom left-hand corner of the screen. Is there a solution to remove it?

This is my code:

```
video = Video(source="F:\Animation.mov",
                           state='stop',
                           options={'allow_stretch': False},
                           volume=1)

class VideoPlayerApp(App):
  def build(self):
    global fl
    fl = FloatLayout()
    video.play = True
    fl.add_widget(video)
    return fl

VideoPlayerApp().run()
```

If so please, let me know!

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @JohnAnderson I edited the post, now you can read the code

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the white rectangle is there during loading of the `Video` (as you mentioned). You can avoid showing the rectangle by not showing the `Video` `Widget` while it is loading. Here is a code that does that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import NoTransition
from kivy.uix.video import Video


class MyVideo(Video):
    def on_loaded(self, instance, value):
        # switch screen to the video
        self.manager.transition = NoTransition()
        self.manager.current = 'video'

kv = '''
ScreenManager:
    Screen:
        name: "dummy_screen"
    Screen:
        name: "video"
        MyVideo:
            id: 
            manager: root
            source: "F:\Animation.mov"
            state: 'play'  # causes the video to be loaded
            options: {'allow_stretch': False}
            volume: 1
'''


class VideoPlayerApp(App):
  def build(self):
      return Builder.load_string(kv)

VideoPlayerApp().run()
```

The above code starts with a dummy screen showing (while the video is loaded). The class `MyVideo` (which extends `Video`) switches to the `video` `Screen` when the video is completely loaded.